# How to hold old value of textarea after changing it's value for a new one?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple textarea :

```
<textarea rows="10%" cols="100%" id="myTextArea">
```

I have a function that change the value of the textarea whenever I click to a button. The problem is that I'm losing the old value for the new one. Is there a way to keep them all?

```
function changeTextAreaValue1(){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = "value1";
}
function changeTextAreaValue2(){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = "value2";
}
changeTextAreaValue1();
changeTextAreaValue2();
```

I made this simple jsfiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/201/

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you looking to append the new data onto the old data, or are you looking to store the old values in some sort of javascript construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are replacing the text, you need to concatenate to the existing text.

```
var ele = document.getElementById("myTextArea");

function changeTextAreaValue1(){
    ele.value += "value1"; // See the +
}
function changeTextAreaValue2(){
    ele.value += "value2";
}
changeTextAreaValue1();
changeTextAreaValue2();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I'll accept it I think , it's proper

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeTextAreaValue1(){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = "value1";
}
function changeTextAreaValue2(){
    var oldVal = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = oldVal +"value2";
}
changeTextAreaValue1();
changeTextAreaValue2();



<textarea rows="10%" cols="100%" id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/204/)

Comment: yeah, that `var oldVar` has a wrong assignment at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById("myTextArea"),
    previousValue;

function changeTextAreaValue (val) {
    previousValue = el.value;
    el.value = val;
}

changeTextAreaValue("hello");
changeTextAreaValue("world");

// previousVar is now "hello"
```